# Logo is not changing

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a new website and the logo from the homepage is not changing.

My URL: http://sugubat.inbanat.ro/

The logo that I want to appear: https://sugubat.inbanat.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo-sugubat-1.png

The logo that actually appears: https://sugubat.inbanat.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/retina-logo-2.png

I've also delete *The logo that actually appears* from the Media section from WordPress... but nothing.

Have anybody had this problem? Can you help me????

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Without one it will be pretty much impossible for us to tell you why your code is giving incorrect results.

Comment: P.S.: The header is built in Elementor. Layouts > https://sugubat.inbanat.ro/layouts/elementor-header-default/

Comment: probably a caching issue. Empty the browser cache, log out and in again etc.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the WordPress StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to mention `https:` at the beginning and you just mention the address of logo as `//sugubat.inbanat.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/retina-logo-2.png` .

just change the address to:
`https://sugubat.inbanat.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo-sugubat-1.png`